# Looking for movie with quote "People who sit at home and watch sitcoms... those people are dead"

Tags: identify-this-movie, dialogue

I saw a movie around 2000 (which would've been made within 5 years or so of this year) where I heard the line "People who sit at home and watch sitcoms... those people are dead" - this is paraphrase.

I thought it was "Instinct" (with Anthony Hopkins) - and my memory of a man like Anthony Hopkins' character saying this line is fairly clear - but I re-watched the film and did not find the line (I also checked the scripts and transcripts) so this does not look good.

The film was NOT: "Goodfellas", "Trainspotting", "Silence of the Lambs".

Comment: Perhaps Trainspotting?

Comment: @iandotkelly Perhaps indeed... is there anything to support that?

Comment: Well there is a reason why I didn't post it as an answer - I don't have access to any supporting material, or can check the movie myself today.  However its reminiscent of the opening monolog of Trainspotting, and is one of the themes of the movie.

Comment: Trainspotting however has a very definite feel to it - one that is not at all similar to Goodfellas, so it makes me doubt it.

Comment: @iandotkelly Yes... you're right; that opening may well fit. I think the feel is actually suitable for such a quote - although I'm not sure if I can see one of the characters saying it... since they were pretty hopeless

Comment: @iandotkelly I just checked the script at: http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Trainspotting.html  and it does not seem to be there

Comment: Goodfellas?  There is a narration by the leading character of the difference between mob life and mundane life.  Also Fight Club seems in keeping with the quote?

Comment: I do not have the sources to make it a proper answer, it is just vaguely bouncing at the back of my memory!

Comment: @Stefan No worries. The Fight Club quote is: "Don't deal with this the way those dead people do." (about the lye). Unless you were thinking of something else?

Comment: Hmmm .. nothing else springs to mind :(

Comment: @Stefan I could've sworn it was Instinct... 100% - when Hopkins' character was talking about _Illusions_. Yes, :( indeed.

Comment: @d'alar'cop have you considered it's Hopkins, but in another film.  I can imagine Dr Lecter saying it to Clarice in Silence of the Lambs (it's a comment because it's pure conjecture).

Comment: @dav1dsm1th I just checked the script - that's a negatory. Good point about look-alikes though; I thought it may have even been Connery in The Rock... long, grey hair and generally dishevelled look

Answer (score 12):

Could this be [Man on the Moon (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125664/)?

Andy Kaufman is being offered a job in a sitcom, and is talking about [canned laughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laugh_track) (emphasis added):

> - **I hate sitcoms**, George. I've never liked them.
>   [...]
>   - And sitcoms are the lowest form of entertainment.
>   - I mean, it's just stupid jokes and canned laughter!
>   - You don't know why it's there, but it's there.
>   - **Those are dead people laughing, you know that, those people are dead!**

Comment: Extremely close... And, frankly, this may really be the one - I might just be delirious. But I still believe the quote was more about the people _watching_ the sitcoms being "dead". But, again, I might just be a false memory.